# Understanding volumn in docker compose

Tags: docker

The following is an example given in https://docker-curriculum.com/

```
version: "3"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: es
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  web:
    image: prakhar1989/foodtrucks-web
    command: python app.py
    depends_on:
      - es
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./flask-app:/opt/flask-app
volumes:
    esdata1:
      driver: local
```

and it says `The volumes parameter specifies a mount point in our web container where the code will reside` about the `/opt/flask-app`

I think it means, `/opt/flask-app` is a mount point and it points to the host machines `./flask-app`

However it doesn't say anything about `esdata1` and I can't apply the same explanation as given to `/opt/flask-app` since there's no `esdata1` directory/file in the host machine.

What is happening for the `esdata1` ? 
My guess is that it means creating a volume (The closest thing I can think of is a disk partition)  and name it `esdata1` and mount it on `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`, am I correct on this guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are a bit different things: `volumes` and `bind mounts`. Bind mounts let you specify folder on **host** machine, which would serve as a storage. Volumes (at lease for `local` driver) also have folders on host machines, but their location is managed by Docker and is sometimes a bit more difficult to find.

When you specify volume in `docker-compose.yml`, if your path starts with `/` or `.` it becomes a `bind mount`, like in `web` service. Otherwise, if it is a single verb, it is a `volume`, like for `es` service.

You can inspect all volumes on your host machine by running `docker volume ls`.

> What is happening for the esdata1 ? My guess is that it means creating
>   a volume (The closest thing I can think of is a disk partition) and
>   name it esdata1 and mount it on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data, am I
>   correct on this guess?

That's all correct.

I do not pretend on setting up the rules, but in general, `volumes` are more suitable for sharing common data between several containers, like in `docker-compose`, while `bind mounts` suite better for sharing data from host to container, like some initial configs for services.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, what about persistant data such as DB or elasticsearch data? which of `volumes` or `bind mounts` are preferred for those?

Comment: It depends whether you need this data outside or not. If you use it internally in `docker-compose`, using volume is a better solution.

Comment: Just written an answer few minutes ago on persisting the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54519405/10524386   The last part of the answer relates to the topic

Comment: heh, that's me again actually, I'll be reading the answers there .. Thanks!